# json parsing in android giving type mismatch

Tags: java, android, json

am parsing a json string. When i run my code am receiving json exception which says "type mismatch" at a point where am getting json array from json object.
here is my code

```
String dataFromLogin="{"catego":{"id":"2","fname":"Tashen Jazbi","uname":"tashen",
    "password":"123","pic_url":"","lati":"33.7167","longi":"73.0667","city":"Islamabad",
    "country":"Pakistan","mobid":"000000000000000","street":"xyz",
    "dateandtime":"2013-12-29 18:07:52"}}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(dataFromLogin);
    //JSONObject response = jsonObj.getJSONObject("catego");
    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("catego");
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        fullname = c.getString("fname");

        uname = c.getString("uname");
        pic_url = c.getString("pic_url");

        lat = c.getString("lati");
        lng = c.getString("longi");

        city = c.getString("city");

        country = c.getString("country");

        street= c.getString("street");
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I couldn't found where am doing wrong. If anyone can help then it'll be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("catego");
```

`catego` is a jsonobject

`{` represents a json object node

`[` represents a json array node

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
JSONObject response = jsonObj.getJSONObject("catego");
```

because "catego" is an object not an array.